# Find the shortest path (or geodesic) on a surface with the equation $z=f(x,y)$. How to proceed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, geodesics

> The problem that I am considering is to find the shortest path (or geodesic) on a surface with the equation $z=f(x,y)$. The path is parameterized by $s$ so that the path goes from $(x(0)$,$y(0)$,$z(0))$ to $(x(1)$,$y(1)$,$z(1))$ (so our parameter $s$ goes from 0 to 1.)

This is how I did this problem: We know that the length of a finite path in regular Euclidean space is given by $$L=\int ds \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2},         $$ where $\dot{x_i} = \frac{dx_i}{ds}$.

Here, we know that $z=f(x,y)$, so I deduced that $$\dot{z}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac {\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac {\partial f }{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \dot{x} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dot{y}$$ Plugging this into the equation for the length, $$ L= ds \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\left(\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\dot{x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \dot{y}\right)^2}$$ Furthermore, $L$ is a functional so we can take the functional derivatives and set them equal to zero to find the shortest path taken, namely $$\frac {\delta F}{\delta x}=0$$ and $$\frac {\delta F}{\delta y}=0,$$ using the fact that $$\frac{\delta F}{\delta x_i}=\frac {\partial F}{\partial x_i}-\frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{x_i}}\right)$$ where $i$ goes from 1 to 2 in this case and $$F=\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\left(\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\dot{x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \dot{y}\right)^2}.$$ So, is this the correct approach to go? I do not want to do it the way with the metric because this is part of a classical mechanics class (part of the variation calculus chapter), but when I do this, the maths gets very tedious. So, how should I proceed?

Comment: You take *functional* derivatives of *functionals*. An example of a functional is the action, $S=\int dt L$, which is probably the thing you want to extremize.

Comment: What this has to do with physics?

Comment: What? $L$ is a functional, so I took the functional derivative. What I am asking is if this is correct and/or there is an easier way to do it, like with lagrange multipliers or something?

Comment: @Josh_P: I'm sorry, please ignore my comment. I was thrown off by a previous version of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to get (I mean conceptually, because technically I think it would be the same) what you want is using the metric tensor indeed. In any other case you will also be using it but not explicitly. What you are doing is totally correct and should be a nice way to "hide" the metric.

The only thing that I would do further is to reorganize your Lagrangian putting all of the derivatives together like:

$
F = \sqrt{\left[1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2\right]\dot x^2+\left[1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2\right]\dot y^2 + 2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dot x\dot y},
$

this might help with the tedious calculations.

This would be the same thing one would get if he were using the metric explicitly instead. By the way, you can check this by parametrizing your surface by

$
X(x,y) = (x,y,f(x,y))
$

and calculating the metric in the usual way as defined on Euclidian surfaces

$
g_{ij} = <X_i,X_j>,
$

where $X_i$ denotes the partial derivative of $X$ with respect to $i=x,y$. Then your Lagrangian would be given by

$
F = \sqrt{g_{ij}\dot x^i \dot x^j} = \sqrt{\left[1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2\right]\dot x^2+\left[1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2\right]\dot y^2 + 2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dot x\dot y}.
$

Addendum: sometimes to minimize $\sqrt{g_{ij}\dot x^i \dot x^j}$ is the same thing that to minimize $g_{ij}\dot x^i \dot x^j$, but there are some conditions to be satisfied in order to get this equivalence. I don't remember these conditions to be honest, but you shoud try looking for it, certainly it will also help with the messy calculations.

Comment: thank you very much! Sorry, I am not familiar with the metric very much; what are the arrows in $<X_i,X_j>$?